# UITableViewCell images are resized when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, xcode6.4, haneke

I used HanekeSwift to set the images in my `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. My code below works but the images are resized when I start scrolling through the list. How can I prevent the images from resizing?

```
//Load pet image
var petImage : String = pet["pet_image"] as! String
var petUrl = NSURL(string: petImage)
var cellImageView = cell.imageView
cellImageView?.hnk_setImageFromURL(petUrl!, format: Format<UIImage>(name: "original"))
```

Here are my screenshots:

First load: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10131270/first-load.png

After scrolling: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10131270/after-scrolling.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `contentMode` property on the `cellImageView` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added these two lines to make it work: `cellImageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill` and `cellImageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 66)`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @pnavk, here is the solution:

```
//Load pet image
var petImage : String = pet["pet_image"] as! String
var petUrl = NSURL(string: petImage)
var cellImageView = cell.imageView
cellImageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
cellImageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 66)
cellImageView?.hnk_setImageFromURL(petUrl!, placeholder: UIImage(named: "Star66"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** First add Content mode e.g `imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

**Step 2** Give the frame e.g `imgView.frame = defaultVideoImgCellSize`

**Step 3** Then set image to imageview e.g `imgView.image = img`

**Note** Set contentMode and frame before setting image to imageview

**Whole Example**

```
let imgView = UIImageView()
imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imgView.frame = defaultVideoImgCellSize
imgView.image = img
cell.addSubview(imgView)
```